# mysql query to select highest temperature today

Tags: mysql, datetime

Just learning MYSQL sorry and didn't find the answer from searching here as I am confused about timezones etc.

I have a table like the following;

- time (datetime type with time in my timezone in it - eg "2014-11-21 14:23:45")
- temp_c (double with temperature at that time)

The server is in a different timezone so I am getting mixed up in how to limit the rows to be sometime today.

So basically I want to find the maximum temperature so far today in my timezone and when it occured, as well as the minimum temperature and when that occured.

Comment: DATETIME does not save timezones

Comment: @juergend But if he calculates `DATE(time)` it will be determined in a specific timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET time_zone = 'your time zone';
SELECT MAX(temp_c) 
FROM YourTable
WHERE DATE(time) = DATE(NOW());
```

Replace `your time zone` with your actual time zone. This can either be an offset from GMT like `-05:00` for 5 hours west of GMT, or a zone name like `US/Eastern`.

```
SET time_zone = 'US/Eastern';
```

For more information on time zones in MySQL see

[How do I set the time zone of MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql)